# Having issue reading HTTP response code for a stream (works with normal url)

Tags: php, http-headers, httpresponse, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I try to detect if a stream (ogg or mp3 file) exists, or not.

I wanted to use get_headers but i've noticed that my hosting has disabled this function.

I can activate it in htaccess but for some reasons it doesn't work properly.

Anyway, i decided to use cURL and it works if i try to detect if a url exist :

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://stackoverflow.com' ) );
        curl_exec( $curl );
        $response_code = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
        curl_close( $curl );
        echo 'http://stackoverflow.com : response code '.$response_code.'<br />';
        if ($response_code == 200)
        { 
            echo 'url exists';
        } else {
            echo "url doesn't exist";
        }
```

It works fine. I've tried with a false url and the response code is 0.

I don't know why it doesn't work with my stream, like this one :

```
http://locus.creacast.com:9001/StBaume_grotte.ogg
```

I thought about a server issue but i've tried with other streams found on the net (like this one : http://radio.rim952.fr:8000/stream.mp3) and i still can't get the response code.

```
$curl_2 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array( $curl_2, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://locus.creacast.com:9001/StBaume_grotte.ogg' ) );
        curl_exec( $curl_2 );
        $response_code_2 = curl_getinfo( $curl_2, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
        curl_close( $curl_2 );
        echo '<br /><br />http://locus.creacast.com:9001/StBaume_grotte.ogg : '.$response_code_2.'<br />';
        if ($response_code_2 == 200)
        { 
            echo 'url existe';
        } else {
            echo "url n'existe pas";
        }
```

So i guess it is not a server issue but it is related to the type of url / file.

Do you know what i could check ? My response code is always 0 even if file exists and it is very slow to get the response code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the following code to get the response header. You could increase the timeout for slower URL's but keep in mind that it would also effect your own page load.

```
$options['http'] = array(
  'method' => "HEAD", 
  'follow_location' => 0,
  'ignore_errors' => 1,
  'timeout' => 0.2
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$body = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);
if (!empty($http_response_header))
{
  //var_dump($http_response_header); 
  //to see what tou get back for usefull help

  if (substr_count($http_response_header[0], ' 404')>0)
    echo 'not found'
}
```

UPDATE:

I noticed the problem is with the body. It looks like it tries to download everything even with a HEAD request. So I altered the request to a simple `fopen` and it works.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://radio.rim952.fr:8000/stream.mp3';

// Try and open the remote stream
if (!$stream = @fopen($url, 'r')) {
  // If opening failed, inform the client we have no content

  if (!empty($http_response_header))
  {
    var_dump($http_response_header); 
  }

  exit('Unable to open remote stream');
}

echo 'file exists';
?>
```

I tested with the rim952 url because the other doesnt even load anymore in firefox here. I tested by changing the request to stream.mp3xx to generate a 404 which comes almost instantly.

Comment: Thank, your answer helps me.
So, in order to use your solution, i had to activate "allow_url_fopen".

After that, i have an error "failed to open stream: Connection timed out". So i guess now the issue is related to the time it takes to get the response code. What i don't understand, if i try to open stream url, the connection works and it is fast, but if i try to get the response code, it is very slow and there is a time out.